# Regarding the future of Golden visas in the EU

Tags: european-union

Half a month ago,  I had asked [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/55358/what-power-does-the-supra-national-european-parliament-have-regarding-the-contro) question which was part of my research.

I am closely following the developments about the Golden visa schemes in the EU and EU's efforts to stop them and put them to an end. In a nutshell, the EU (Commission and Parliament) thinks that they are very risky, bringing criminals, tax evaders etc.. into the EU. EU has formally asked member states to phase them out, but it is clear no member state wants to do that.

My previous question has an answer that concludes that EU **cannot** make the member states phase these schemes out because the EU Council (consisting of member states' Governments ministers) would never agree to do that. It would require both the EU council and EU parliament to agree to pass a decision. But that is clearly not possible as member states want their schemes to continue.

In this context, how would the EU manage to get rid off these schemes when it is impossible to convince the EU Council? What alternative tactics are likely to be implemented that EU Council would have no problem with but will lead to a decrease in the popularity of the golden visas?

Comment: If the Council is not on board, “the EU” does not think or want anything. As the answer to your earlier question revealed, the Council is a key institution. I am not sure what you are referring to but I am guessing you mean (some part of) the EU *Commission*.

Comment: Yes you are right. EU Commission and EU Parliament want to end such schemes. EU Council is unlikely to agree.

Comment: @Relaxed Do see my comment to Erwan's answer.

Comment: This is an important distinction, you should really stop thinking and writing “the EU this” or “the EU that”. The EU hasn't reached a consensus. In this like in so many other matters (this isn't even the most contentious or most important one), the Commission cannot easily have its ways and is limited to writing reports, building coalitions, etc. to influence the process, nothing more. The Parliament has even less power.

Comment: +1 I agree with you. Doing a google search like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=EU+urges+to+terminate+golden+visa&oq=EU+urges+to+terminate+golden+visa&aqs=chrome..69i57.5725j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) one reveals that it is the EU *Parliament* that wants to abolish golden visa schemes. So you are right, I will keep that in mind not to refer it as "the EU wants this or that".

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, the Commission is extremely worried about the unraveling of the Schengen border-free area but very shy about using its enforcement powers in this matter, it is taking an activist stance on tax ruling, it hasn't found a long-term solution to the refugee situation or the rule-of-law issues in Poland and Hungary, it's struggling to be relevant on the Covid-19 response and getting everybody on board with their economic recovery package. The visa issue is far down the list of things over which it might to go on a war path with member states.

Comment: Well-meaning principled initiatives that go nowhere is kind of the Parliament's trademark. They will vote on it from time to time and that'll be it. There is nothing they would or could do to force the issue. I am not sure what else you expect to hear by asking follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Politically speaking, there are a few options that a group of (strong) EU member states could use to coerce others to drop their golden visas schemes:

- Political quid pro quo across various issues: identify something that the target state needs or wants and exchange support on this issue against the target state dropping their golden visa policy. Naturally the success of this kind of strategy depends how much the anti-golden visa countries are ready to give away for this to happen.
- An obvious variant of the first option is some kind of financial deal which compensates the golden visa countries for the loss of income, for instance by giving them access to some special loans for specific development projects for instance. This would be some morally questionable backroom politics, but it's not outside the realm of reality.
- raising a strong PR campaign which would hurt the reputation of the target countries if they don't drop their golden visas schemes. This is fairly doable because the golden visas schemes are usually something that regular citizens don't like, but to be successful such a campaign would have to cause enough reputational damage (e.g. loss of tourism income) for the target countries to re-consider their golden visas schemes.
- Threaten to leave the Schengen area: if free movement within the EU was restricted to only a few countries, the golden visas would lose a lot of their appeal. This is unrealistic though, since free movement is a crucial symbol of the EU identity.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Regarding the last point; you mention that although unrealistic, the EU could threaten to kick them out of Schengen Area. How likely is an event that the EU decides to restrict all the people who obtained citizenship through golden visas from movement across the EU and just stay in the country that granted them golden visa? That is, is it possible that in the end, if the EU cannot make these countries give up golden visa schemes, the EU will amend the Free Movement directive to restrict the movement of such golden visa persons to the country that granted them golden visa?

Comment: This will, in effect create a 2 tier EU citizenship, one the normal one and the other golden visa one, the latter being deprived of the right of free movement.  This could make schemes in countries like Malta, Cyprus, Bulgaria etc unpopular as investors generally want to access the EU, not the countries they invested in especially when they are like Malta or Cyprus. Moreover, even if the schemes remain popular, free movement restrictions will stop criminals from travelling to other member states and thus those criminals' activities will only be restricted to the country that granted them visa.

Comment: I think this is a likely action. What is your opinion? Could EU use this tactic? Or is EU against creating a 2 tier citizenship?

Comment: @AndrewRozario What you propose seems unthinkable to me. What Erwan suggested is different: kicking the whole country out to exert pressure. That's not likely but legally and politically less of a breach of EU principles.

Comment: @Relaxed Hmm...I understand what Erwan suggested was different. Political pressure is indeed a great tool to achieve things. I am however curious why did my proposal seem unthinkable? Consider this. If EU Commission proposes to amend EU law to bar golden visa persons from using the Free Movement rights (I know of one case where the US restricts "golden passport citizens" of Micronesia, Palau and Marshall islands from using the right of indefinite stay without conditions in the US that regular citizens by birth or naturalization (with 5 years residence) enjoy.) (1/3)

Comment: This way the US effectively creates 2 tiers of citizenship for Palau and those other islands; one that can enjoy right to enter and stay in the US indefinitely without visa, and the other (golden passport) that doesn't enjoy this right. So if EU Commission proposes to amend the law in this way, countries like Germany, France, Italy, Ireland, Switzerland etc.. won't have ANY problem with it, but countries like Malta, Cyprus and Bulgaria WILL have problem as their golden visa will lose its sheen as golden visa will no longer lead to free access to the wealthy EU countries. (2/3)

Comment: @AndrewRozario That would be a fundamental attack on the member states' sovereignty and redefinition of the nature of EU citizenship. The Commission could hardly do that through secondary EU law, freedom of movement and EU citizenship are anchored in the treaties (and confirmed by EUCJ case law). The comparison with the US is relevant: the EU Commission is not in a kind of quasi-colonial relationship with member states, that's just not how it works. If there was even the suggestion of something like that, I fully expect France, Germany, etc. to be strongly opposed and to kill it within hours.

Comment: This way EU commission proposes something that EU parliament is ready to accept and the EU Council will have a minority opposition (as minsters of countries like France and Germany will have no problem as their countries won't suffer while a handful of countries like Malta and Cyprus will suffer as people will no longer be able to buy Malta passport **to access the whole EU because of the new amendment**. (3/3)

Comment: Isn't this a good solution? EU Commission won't attack on members' sovereignty this way, as inter-member country travel is a domain where EU has control. Just inter-country travel of golden passport holders have to be restricted. And inter-country travel restriction would not be a domain where member countries individually have any power, right?

Comment: +1 for that reply. Anything on my further comments? (Really liking your arguments. You are helping me consolidate my knowledge about the powers of EU commission, parliament and council) Also, did you mean "US comparison is "irrelevant"? Maybe that's a typo?

Comment: @AndrewRozario No, it's not a good solution, it cuts deeply into a country's sovereign power to decide who is a citizen or not and what being a citizen entails by going around that country's legal system and directly conferring additional rights to some citizens over others. As mentionned earlier, EU citizenship and freedom of movement are defined in the treaties themselves, it's not something the EU Commission could dispose of at will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112599/discussion-between-relaxed-and-andrew-rozario).

Comment: Your thoughts @Erwan? Excited to see what you think about this too! You can post in the chatroom.

Comment: @AndrewRozario I just posted in the chatroom before seeing your comment here

Answer (score -1):

I assume that Golden Visas are actually EU citizenships in exchange for a large investment or something like this.

I can try to give a solution which is already possible under EU Directive 2004/38/EC.

Let's say we have a Russian citizen who recently acquired a citizenship of Cyprus. Then all other EU member states may restrict freedom of movement and residence of such citizen based on a threat against public health, policy, or security according to Article 27 of EU Directive 2004/38/EC.

Every person has a name, date and place of birth regardless of a citizenship. Therefore, even if Cyprus will not inform other EU member states that it gave a citizenship of Cyprus to a certain Russian citizen, other EU member states may restrict freedom of movement and residence of such person.

Citizenship law is not in competence of EU, so I cannot imagine that EU can prohibit Golden Visas - every state will see it little bit differently.

Comment: Note that Golden visas are akin to Permanent residence (or a pathway to PR). Golden passports mean selling citizenship, which is also the case for 3 EU countries.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your effort to find a solution. +1 for that. But is it okay that member states reject freedom of movement and residence of such citizen based on a threat against public health, policy, or security? For no reason?

Comment: EU states may restrict any person based on a threat against public health, policy, or security. So it can be applied also to third-country citizens with a (permanent) residence card which extemps e.g. from Schengen visa requirement in other Schengen states.

Comment: How would the member states know who became a citizen by golden passport?

Comment: @AndrewRozario from CJEU: "Expulsion on grounds of public policy or public security — Conduct representing a genuine, present and sufficiently serious threat affecting one of the fundamental interests of society" Therefore, if we talk about a known criminal or something like that then it is possible. Otherwise not.

Comment: If we talk about a known criminal, then the EU states would know. Otherwise, why would you restrict every person who got Golden Visa/Passport unless they are threat to public health, policy, or security? I personally have something like Golden EU Passport because I found the right ancester. Should I be also restricted?

Comment: Oh, you've got a good point there. One of the big concerns of the EU was that such schemes could be used by terrorists/criminals to circulate throughout the EU. But when member states can reject their entry based on public threat, why is there so much fuss about the schemes? The other concern, money laundering/tax evasion can easily be countered by proper vetting. Why is there so much concern when the solution is so simple?

Comment: The solution exist, I don't think that it is simple. Once in Schengen area, the chances that you will be checked by police are low even if you are not allowed to enter the country.

Comment: *"I personally have something like Golden EU Passport because I found the right ancester. Should I be also restricted?"* What do you mean?

Also, there is another threat that potential criminals with no criminal backgrounds could enter the EU by golden visa and circulate freely to start their criminal career.

Comment: I got citizenship after my ancester born in 1904, thats all. Everybody is a potential criminal...

Comment: In that case you claim your right by ancestry not Golden visa

Comment: Roman Abramovich granted Israeli citizenship https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/may/28/roman-abramovich-granted-israeli-citizenship-tel-aviv-chelsea This is more like a Golden Passport, despite based on "law of return". Anyway, at the end it is up to Israel how they decide. The UK may still restrict an Israeli citizen to enter UK if they want.

Comment: umm...that one isn't about golden visa. He was granted citizenship more or less like "his ancestors were from Israel". Golden visas are about buying PR

Comment: "Abramovich, who is Jewish and has been a regular visitor to Israel, has donated millions to Israeli research and development projects and invested in local firms. Ynet said he had bought a former hotel in Tel Aviv, on the Mediterranean coast." I don't want to speculate but citizenship law may be flexible... Whatever, Israel made a decision and I respect that.

Comment: Invoking “public health, public security or public policy” merely because someone recently acquired citizenship through a particular route will not pass muster. Even past criminal activity is not enough, you cannot block anyone who has a criminal record, the decision must be based on a specific risk assessment. That standard is more restrictive than you seem to suggest.

Comment: @Relaxed I understand that. That's why I already posted here: CJEU: "Expulsion on grounds of public policy or public security — Conduct representing a genuine, present and sufficiently serious threat affecting one of the fundamental interests of society" I am saying that if we have a known criminal (something like a head of organized crime) the EU states may invoke public policy, health, or security. If you stole few things many years ago that's a different story...

Comment: “Known criminal” is a bit vague, the distinction is not only about the seriousness of the crime, the key point is that it cannot be automatic and must be based on some evidence that you currently pose a risk. If you understand that, your answer doesn't seem to reflect it.

Comment: I understand it, I was reading judgements from CJEU on this topic. My understanding of this question is that Golden Visa/Passport for e.g. Russian/Chinesse oligarchs by e.g. Cyprus is a problem. Therefore, I am saying that if we have some very obvious case, then we can invoke public policy, security, or health. Of course it cannot be done automatically. I am also not saying that all Golden Visa/Passports are a problem. I am also not saying that public policy, security, or health will solve everything - but this tool already exist.